# Query showing which queries are processing with info about it in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I'm pretty sure there is a query that shows which queries / processes are running in realtime. It shows which machine or user are running it, when they started and when they finish, and info like that about the query/process.

Anyone knows what query or queries can help me to see this info?

Comment: [Monitoring Database Activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring.html) in the manual

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find what you need querying the view pg_stat_activity. There is more information available regarding that view here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html